Why i take this result and how can i solve it?
i use macOS in my internship for mobile developing with flutter.
I am suffer from this two problem from last Thursday morning.
Flutter device daemon #5 exited (exit code 127), stderr: env: bash: No such file or directory
The Flutter device daemon cannot be started. Please check your configuration and restart the IDE.  You may need to increase the maximum number of file handles available globally.`

When i was try to build APK, android studio was returning NO SDK Environment problem. I tried some terminal codes to solve it. But now i'm suffer from new problems , Android studio doesn't debugs code and returns errors above. And i see like this errors in my terminal when i started it
.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh:42: command not found: uname
   .sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh:75: command not found: find
   .sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh:103: command not found: _sdkman_echo_debug
   .rvm/scripts/rvm:12: command not found: uname
   .rvm/scripts/rvm:29: command not found: ps

and terminal returns
command not found:

for commands like nano open sudo
and when i write flutter returns env: bash: No such file or directory to me

My guess is one of the command typed in terminal reset the PATH environment variable.
PATH is usually set to a list of folders where binaries/commands are found. Without this variable properly set, you get the kind of errors message you mention.
I am more familiar with Linux than MacOS, thus I'll suggest to consult pages like https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/

I used this command. Then the terminal started to accept commands like sudo nano, at the last I installed android studio as administrator mode.
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Now I can use all of them again
